# AmCharts with multiple dataSet

Tags: javascript, amcharts

We have site with a lot of temperature indications. Also there are pill intake data. Customer wants it done using AmCharts. I haven't found the correct example to make this project. After searching in google, I've found [this code example](https://jsfiddle.net/a0p3vm8r/2/), which explains the similar one.

```
var chartData = [];
var chartData2 = [];

generateChartData();

function generateChartData() {
  var firstDate = new Date();
  firstDate.setDate( firstDate.getDate() - 500 );
  firstDate.setHours( 0, 0, 0, 0 );

  for ( var i = 0; i < 500; i++ ) {
    var newDate = new Date( firstDate );
    newDate.setDate( newDate.getDate() + i );

    var a1 = Math.round( Math.random() * ( 40 + i ) ) + 100 + i;

    chartData.push( {
      date: newDate,
      value1: a1
    } );

   if (a1%2 != 0)
   {
      chartData2.push( {
        date: newDate,
        value2: a1
      });
  }
 }
}

var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  type: "stock",
  "theme": "light",

  "dataSets": [ 
  {
    "fieldMappings": [ {
      "fromField": "value1",
      "toField": "value1"
    }
    ],
    "dataProvider": chartData,
    "categoryField": "date",
    "compared" : true
  },

  {
    "fieldMappings": [ {
    "fromField": "value2",
    "toField": "value2"
  }
],
    "dataProvider": chartData2,
    "categoryField": "date",
    "compared": true
  }
],


 "panels": [ {
   recalculateToPercents:"never",

   "valueAxes" : [
     {"id":"axis1"},
     {"id":"axis2"}
   ],

   "stockGraphs": [ 
   {
     "id": "g1",
     "title": "Graph #1",
     "lineThickness": 2,
     "valueField": "value1",
     "useDataSetColors": false,
     "valueAxis" : "axis1",
   }, 

  {
    "id": "g2",
    "title": "Graph #2",
    "lineThickness": 5,
    "valueField": "value2",
    "useDataSetColors": false,
    "connect" : false,
    "valueAxis" : "axis2",
    "comparable": true,
    "compareField": "value2"
  }]
 }],

 "chartScrollbarSettings": {
    "graph": "g1"
 },

 "chartCursorSettings": {
    "valueBalloonsEnabled": true,
    "fullWidth": true,
    "cursorAlpha": 0.1,
    "valueLineBalloonEnabled": true,
    "valueLineEnabled": true,
    "valueLineAlpha": 0.5
  },

  "periodSelector": {
     "position": "bottom",
     "periods": [ {
     "period": "MM",
     "selected": true,
     "count": 1,
     "label": "1 month"
   }, {
     "period": "YYYY",
     "count": 1,
     "label": "1 year"
   }, {
     "period": "YTD",
     "label": "YTD"
   }, {
     "period": "MAX",
     "label": "MAX"
   } ]
 }
});
```

But the reason it's not usable for me, is the case, when pill intake period of time is not in temperature indication data set time period. In AmChart we must choose the main data set, so if we add new item with date grater than main data set's period in second(not main) data set, its not even visible.

Hope you will help me with this case, after a lot of time searching solution, I didn't even get closer to the right solution.

Comment: Is it required to use jquery? if not pls remove the tag.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, [this is probably what you're looking for](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/syncing-stock-charts-data-set-timestamps/)

Comment: @xorspark it almost helped me, not all dataSets I load in chart are showing. I have 20 dataSets distributed for 7 days and only first dataSet is shown, other are hidden and not presented even in chartScrollbar.

Comment: Post your code and sample of your data as a fiddle, please.

Comment: @xorspark, I realized the solution, I just haven't added the amchart's handler, [full code](https://jsfiddle.net/s7ghcyzn/). But I have other problems: only first dataset is shown in scrollbar. Also there must be some points with different balloon text, with different appearance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add special [plugin code](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/syncing-stock-charts-data-set-timestamps/)(**initHandler** method) for inserting new dataSets. In this case all data will be shown. But there are some problems with scrollbar: only first dataSet is shown and there is no solution to show all dataSets with gaps in this charting library.